# How to get only selected value from Grid-view c#?

Tags: sharepoint-server, gridview

In my sharepoint list 3000 items are present.I am displaying this items in Gridview in radio buttoncontrol in single selection.At a time user can select only one item.

But using gdvColumns.Rows it will looping all the items.
I want to get only selected item. How can  i achieve this ?

```
protected void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strSelectedValue = "";
            //Multiple Contractingparty Added
            string strFinalSelectedValue = "";
            if (menuTab.Items[0].Selected)
            {
                if (strType == "Single")
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gdvColumns.Rows)
                    {
                        string strDataKeys = Convert.ToString(gdvColumns.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value);
                        if (strType == "Single")
                        {
                            RadioButton rbSelect = (RadioButton)gvr.FindControl("rbSelect");
                            if (rbSelect.Checked == true)
                            {
                                rbSelect.Checked = false;
                                if (aDtblClause.Select("Title = '" + strDataKeys.Replace("'", "''") + "'").Length == 0)
                                {
                                    aDtblClause.Rows.Clear();
                                    DataRow aDrColumn = aDtblClause.NewRow();
                                    aDrColumn["RID"] = aDtblClause.Rows.Count + 1;
                                    aDrColumn["Title"] = strDataKeys;
                                    aDtblClause.Rows.Add(aDrColumn);
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```